# select repeated row observations with the least absolute difference

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame like this:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                  vars = c(1,2,5, 1,3, 0,2,4,-1))

> df
  id vars
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  1    5
4  2    1
5  2    3
6  3    0
7  3    2
8  3    4
9  3   -1
```

In this data frame each `id` can have several observations.
I now want to select for each `id` the pair (2 observations) that have the least absolute difference for `vars`.

In the above case that would be

```
  id vars
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  2    1
4  2    3
5  3    0
6  3   -1
```

for `id` 1, values 1 and 2 have the lowest absolute difference,
`id` 2 only has 2 observations so both are automatically selected.
for the `id` 3 the selected vars would be 0 and -1 because the absolute difference is 1, lower than all other combinations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to do all the comparisons (or, you can let `arrange` do your comparisons for you), because once you've sorted the values each value is already beside the value for which the difference is minimized.

```
df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  arrange(vars) %>% 
  slice(which.min(diff(vars)) + 0:1)

# # A tibble: 6 x 2
# # Groups:   id [3]
#      id  vars
#   <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1
# 2     1     2
# 3     2     1
# 4     2     3
# 5     3    -1
# 6     3     0
```

data.table version

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[df[order(vars), .I[which.min(diff(vars)) + 0:1], id]$V1]

#    id vars
# 1:  3   -1
# 2:  3    0
# 3:  1    1
# 4:  1    2
# 5:  2    1
# 6:  2    3
```

Comment: very concise and easy to add to my existing `group_by` function, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not the most concise but works. Probably somebody can improve the idea.

```
df1%>%group_by(id)%>%mutate(vars2=which.min(abs(diff(combn(num(vars),2)))))%>%
  mutate(vars1=ifelse(vars%in%combn(num(vars),2)[,vars2],vars,NA))%>%select(id,vars1)%>%.[complete.cases(.),]

# A tibble: 6 x 2
# Groups:   id [3]
     id vars1
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     1     2
3     2     1
4     2     3
5     3     0
6     3    -1
```

The main idea is to do the difference on all the possible combinations of the values of each group. `vars2` keeps the column with the lowest difference. If the value is one of the two present in the `vars2` column, it is kept. Else, it is set as `NA`. Then, only complete cases are returned.